# html, I need to display a specific image when a specific button is clicked

Tags: html

There are two images named mumbai.jpg and delhi.jpg.
Two buttons are there, I want to show particular image when the particular button is clicked. Also the image should be displayed in the same window.
eg. clicking on "mumbai" button will show the mumbai.jpg image.Then if i click on 'delhi' button it will display delhi.jpg in same frame,replacing the mumbai.jpg image.I am beginner in HTML please help.

here is my code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Image Display Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            <!--
            function showImage(){
                document.getElementById('1').style.visibility="visible";        
            }
            -->    
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="Mumbai" onclick="showImage();"/>
        <img id="1" src="mumbai.jpg" style="visibility:hidden"/>

        <input type="button" value="Delhi" onclick="showImage();"/>
        <img id="1" src="delhi.jpg" style="visibility:hidden"/>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements in HTML must have a unique `id` (identifier), they cannot have the same `id` like you are using.

One solution to your problem would be to pass `this` into your `showImage` method. Then you can use `elem.nextElementSibling` to get the element next to the button clicked. This will allow you to get the image src which you can then use to set the `src` of the target image/frame.

See working example below:

```css
/* Ignore css */
img {
  height: 150px;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Image Display Test</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function showImage(elem) {
      document.getElementById("display-frame").src = elem.nextElementSibling.src;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" value="Mumbai" onclick="showImage(this);" />
  <img id="1" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1536775904534-7b743734d424?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=02d0a675c0da008dc7587a35509ecf69&w=1000&q=80" style="display:none" />

  <input type="button" value="Delhi" onclick="showImage(this);" />
  <img id="2" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523960666814-f9b47d1e9ed3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" style="display:none" />
  
  <img id="display-frame"/>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this below code.

```js
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#button-one").click(function(){
                $("#1").toggle();

            });

            $("#button-two").click(function(){
                $("#2").toggle();
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button-one">Mumbai</button>
        <img id="1" src="http://www.slipperelectrical.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/dummy-image.jpg" style="display:none;"/>

        <button id="button-two">Delhi</button>
        <img id="2" src="https://dummyimage.com/vga" style="display:none;"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Image Display Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showImage(index) {
            var src=["https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523960666814-f9b47d1e9ed3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80",
                     "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1536775904534-7b743734d424?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=02d0a675c0da008dc7587a35509ecf69&w=1000&q=80"]
            document.getElementById("display-frame").src = src[index];
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        img {
            height: 150px;
            width: auto;
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" value="Delhi" onclick="showImage(0);" />
    <input type="button" value="Show the first image again" onclick="showImage(1);" />
    <img id="display-frame"/ src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1536775904534-7b743734d424?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=02d0a675c0da008dc7587a35509ecf69&w=1000&q=80">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This code solution satisfies the question but could you please [edit] the answer to include just a little explanation to support the code?

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove this <— —> in your script